# crash at c++ STL map.find() when using boost::asio::ip::address as the key

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, stl

I have following program which crashed at map.find(). I am not getting why there is a crash. Any reason why I am having a crash. Thanks for your help and time.
Please pay attention to **4th** line in the function

```
void UploadStatisticModule::SubmitUploadSpeedInfo(boost::asio::ip::address address, boost::uint32_t size)
    {
        upload_speed_info_.SubmitUploadedBytes(size);
        boost::uint32_t upload_speed = upload_speed_info_.GetSpeedInfo().NowUploadSpeed / 1024;
        DACStatisticModule::Inst()->SubmitP2PUploadSpeedInKBps(upload_speed);

        std::map<boost::asio::ip::address, SpeedInfoStatistic>::iterator iter = m_upload_map.find(address);

        if (iter != m_upload_map.end())
        {
            iter->second.SubmitUploadedBytes(size);
        }
        else
        {
            m_upload_map.insert(std::make_pair(address, SpeedInfoStatistic()));
            m_upload_map[address].Start();
            m_upload_map[address].SubmitUploadedBytes(size);
        }
    }
```

Below is the crash stack,it seems finally crashed at **boost::asio::ip::operator<()**

```
Thread : Crashed: Thread
0 0x0071e37c boost::asio::ip::operator<(boost::asio::ip::address const&, boost::asio::ip::address const&) (address.hpp:233)


1 0x0073dcb9 std::_Rb_tree<boost::asio::ip::address, std::pair<boost::asio::ip::address const, statistic::SpeedInfoStatistic>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<boost::asio::ip::address const, statistic::SpeedInfoStatistic> >, std::less<boost::asio::ip::address>, std::allocator<std::pair<boost::asio::ip::address const, statistic::SpeedInfoStatistic> > >::find(boost::asio::ip::address const&) (stl_function.h:227)


2 0x0073c29b statistic::UploadStatisticModule::SubmitUploadSpeedInfo(boost::asio::ip::address, unsigned int) (stl_map.h:542)
```

Comment: How address is created? Is it v4, or v6?

Comment: There is nothing special in `operator<`. It's likely your threading code is wrong. Either dead reference, race condition or other in "pink elephants" style.

Comment: I didn't create the address,I just got it from the endpoint.So it may be either v4 or v6